# Cant run node js as root

Tags: node.js

I have Node js running on my Raspberry pi. When I run
$ node -v 
it gives me the version number but when I run 
$ sudo node -v
It returns node: not found

I need to run it as root, any ideas?

Comment: Try `sudo -E node -v`. It should help.

Answer (score 7):

When you run it as root, your path is different.  If you modify your path as root, or specify the full path to the Node.js executable, it will work.